# Does Facebook have any "legal binding" with the word "wall"?

Tags: facebook, legal

I intend to use "wall" in the same way that Facebook does.

Does Facebook have any "legal binding" with the word `wall` and if so, what?

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking because you are thinking of using the term "Wall" in your own application then you *might* be on shaky ground.

How shaky that ground would be would depend on many factors - not least of which was how popular your site became. A small site might not bother them, but a high profile site which could be seen as a competitor probably would.

There's nothing to stop you having a part of your application where other users post comments, photographs and links to a page on a user's profile - Facebook can't copyright the idea - however if you were to call it a user's "Wall" then it *could* be seen as infringing on Facebook to some degree.

Far better to come up with your own term. As to what that term could be - you'll have to give more details about your application, your target market etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any company or entity can have a legal binding with an English word. Only with words they create themselves, like car models or soft drink names, but not with a word that exists in the Dictionary.

Comment: It's not just the word, but the context in which that word is used. Take "Windows" for example...

Comment: Ah, agreed. If I were to launch an OS called Windows, I would expect some fire from MS. Well in that case, I'd use a different term or use it in a different context.